# Multiple leaflets in a grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, leaflet, r-grid

I have 4 leaflet objects: A, B, C, D. I would like to plot them in a 2 by 2 grid, but I have been having a difficult time trying to do this.

My initial thought was to use ggplot and facet_grid, but ggplot does not know how to deal with objects of class  leaflet.

I would appreciate the help!

Comment: The leaflet output is a htmlwidget. I would recommend `shiny` or `flexdashboard` to create a grid. They both can handle that type of output.

Comment: The `mapview` library has some functions to deal with this. [See the section in this webpage on syncing.](http://pierreroudier.github.io/teaching/20170626-Pedometrics/20170626-web-vis.html)

Comment: Or see [this page](https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/articles/articles/mapview_05-extras.html) for an example of multiple maps in a grid

Answer (score 11):

Leaflets (or any other htmlwidgets) can be combined with `htmltools::tagList`.

In this case, a simple html `table` can handle the layout:

```
library(htmltools)

leaflet_grid <- 
  tagList(
    tags$table(width = "100%",
      tags$tr(
        tags$td(A),
        tags$td(B)
      ),
      tags$tr(
        tags$td(C),
        tags$td(D)
      )
    )
  )
```

You can put the `leaflet_grid` in knitr chunk directly or use

```
browsable(leaflet_grid)
```

to render it from the console.

### Using Shiny fluid page layout

Example with shiny fluid page layout functions:

```
library(shiny)

leaflet_grid_2 <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, A), column(6, B) 
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(6, C), column(6, D) 
  )
)
```

### Using leafsync

```
library(leafsync)
```

To synchronise zoom on all panels, use `sync`:

```
sync(A, B, C, D)
```

And `latticeView` will create panels without synchronising

```
latticeView(A, B, C, D)
```

(see https://r-spatial.github.io/mapview/articles/articles/mapview_05-extras.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to pull out a static image of the 4x4 html output as above. For that you can use the webshot package:

`webshot::webshot(html, directory_to_drop_png_of_html)`

Answer (score -1):

There is a package called "patchwork" which might work out for you.
Patchwork is an extension for ggplot so it should work well with your maps.
You can arrange plots with simple "+" "/" commands.

see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patchwork/vignettes/patchwork.html