# Using a for loop to create multiple plots

Tags: r, for-loop

I am a compete novice at using loops and simplifying my code.
I have a dataset of places with accompanying data that I would like to plot on separate maps. The individual plotting of the maps I can do.
However I would like to automate the process a little bit, I have new data arriving each day and don't want to repeat the process of cleaning the data and rewriting code.
So I thought a `for` loop might be the answer

What I need are separate plots for each `Time` in the data below
So the loop would pull out all the data for each value of `Time` and then plot it.

```
dput(df)  
structure(list(Site = c("O242", "O51", "O59", "O71", "C110", 
"C116", "C120", "C13", "C132", "C134", "C139", "C140", "C29", 
"C30", "C33", "C48", "C56", "C9A", "MP25", "MP67", "B30", "MP2", 
"B101", "B11", "B112", "B15", "B197", "B2", "B217", "B22", "B30", 
"B95", "MP21", "MP25", "MP33", "MP51", "MP56", "MP6", "MP60", 
"MP61", "MP67", "MP77", "EX84", "EX92", "SW130", "O31", "O38", 
"O38B", "O48", "O58", "O59", "O68", "O71", "O72", "O81", "O94", 
"O207", "O209", "O210", "O215"), Time = c(-25, -22, -22, -22, 
-14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, -14, 
-14, -23, -23, -20, -20, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, -11, 
-11, -11, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, 
-10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, -10, 
-10, -10, -10, -10), Code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), lon = c(-1.341280663, -1.343562025, -1.343620358, 
-1.340629756, -1.332551665, -1.329108814, -1.328655294, -1.330835311, 
-1.330715028, -1.33052464, -1.328144549, -1.328287425, -1.329353862, 
-1.329343236, -1.33041446, -1.325353001, -1.327279282, -1.332909331, 
-1.300122834, -1.299148682, -1.310197641, -1.305886812, -1.308725397, 
-1.309505208, -1.309235075, -1.308580716, -1.30959055, -1.308685087, 
-1.309426224, -1.306562029, -1.310197641, -1.307564253, -1.301598673, 
-1.300122834, -1.299510666, -1.299846899, -1.297823339, -1.305388627, 
-1.297220016, -1.297398331, -1.299148682, -1.300378324, -1.333554619, 
-1.338688389, -1.332015649, -1.344951753, -1.344769267, -1.345214102, 
-1.342514477, -1.343145083, -1.343620358, -1.34275518, -1.340629756, 
-1.339067762, -1.338035147, -1.335442485, -1.346461847, -1.34550727, 
-1.34516939, -1.346584124), lat = c(51.76635545, 51.76553293, 
51.76450781, 51.76428383, 51.75689245, 51.75615401, 51.75742817, 
51.75637019, 51.75666667, 51.75740286, 51.7596281, 51.75976378, 
51.75721637, 51.75695556, 51.75701561, 51.75871255, 51.75875955, 
51.75720018, 51.76339382, 51.75986347, 51.76597134, 51.76737513, 
51.76464054, 51.76481595, 51.76542577, 51.76557477, 51.76682149, 
51.7644335, 51.76714421, 51.76681267, 51.76597134, 51.76571265, 
51.76447255, 51.76339382, 51.76268887, 51.76062289, 51.76030512, 
51.76678776, 51.75996884, 51.75968219, 51.75986347, 51.75998767, 
51.76749876, 51.76822905, 51.76474771, 51.76863319, 51.76622254, 
51.7655237, 51.76482531, 51.76430735, 51.76450781, 51.76421526, 
51.76428383, 51.76308822, 51.76434118, 51.76525265, 51.76642077, 
51.7672966, 51.76661139, 51.76598088)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), groups = structure(list(
    Time = c(-25, -23, -22, -20, -20, -14, -14, -11, -11, -11, 
    -10, -10, -10), Code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .rows = structure(list(1L, 19:20, 2:4, 
        22L, 21L, c(7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L
        ), c(5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 18L), 23:30, 32L, 31L, c(33L, 35L, 
        41L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 47L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 58L, 59L), c(34L, 
        36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 44L, 46L, 49L, 55L, 56L, 60L
        ), c(48L, 51L, 54L, 57L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -13L), .drop = TRUE))
```

If I was to do this by hand I would use `dplyr::filter(Time == "x")` then make each plot using `leaflet` like so

```
install.packages("leaflet")
library(leaflet)
statecol<- colorFactor(palette = "viridis", df$Code) #create the colour palette

plots<- leaflet() %>% setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 13.25)
plots %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = df, label = ~as.character(df$Site), radius = 5, color = ~statecol(Code), stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 5) %>%
addLegend('bottomright', pal = statecol, values = df$Code,
          title = 'Codes',
          opacity = 2)
```

If there is a better solution than a loop I'd be happy to try that too.
Hope this is clear and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to put the plotting code in a function which takes a the sole argument a dataframe. To make a map for each unique value of `Time` you could then `split` your data by `Time` and loop over the splitted dataset using the plotting function, where instead of a for loop I use `lapply`. As a result you get a list with plots for each value of `Time`:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

df_split <- df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  split(.$Time)

statecol<- colorFactor(palette = "viridis", df$Code) #create the colour palette

plot_fun <- function(x) {
  leaflet() %>% 
    setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 13.25) |> 
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = x, label = ~as.character(x$Site), radius = 5, color = ~statecol(Code), stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 5) %>%
    addLegend('bottomright', pal = statecol, values = x$Code,
              title = 'Codes',
              opacity = 2)  
}

plots <- lapply(df_split, plot_fun)

length(plots)
#> [1] 7

plots[[1]]
```

[image]

**EDIT** In case you want to keep or use the data from previous plots we could basically use the same code with one small change, i.e. loop over an index and combine (`rbind`) the datasets up to the index value inside the plotting function:

```r
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

df_split <- df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  split(.$Time)

statecol<- colorFactor(palette = "viridis", df$Code) #create the colour palette

plot_fun <- function(ix) {
  x <- do.call(rbind, df_split[seq(ix)])
  leaflet() %>% 
    setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 13.25) |> 
    addTiles() %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = x, label = ~as.character(x$Site), radius = 5, color = ~statecol(Code), stroke = FALSE, fillOpacity = 5) %>%
    addLegend('bottomright', pal = statecol, values = x$Code,
              title = 'Codes',
              opacity = 2)  
}

plots <- lapply(seq_along(df_split), plot_fun)

plots[[3]]
```

[image]

```r
plots[[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, but I just realised there is a flaw in my plot plan, I also need to keep the previous plots data and add it to the next plot, is that complicated?

Comment: See my edit. Hope I got it right.

Comment: Hm. Hard to tell what went wrong. I just made an edit to my edit (: and included two of the outputted plots which also shows that the data for plot 3 is also present in plot 5.

Comment: Sorry @stefan I deleted the comment that said it wasn't working, there was a section of code that I didn't add, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

one approach is to store the *Time*-wise leaflet maps in a column of your `tibble`:

```
## create your base map (only needed once):
base_map <- leaflet() %>% 
               setView(lng = -1.324640, lat = 51.770462, zoom = 13.25) %>%
               addTiles()


all_plots <- 
    df %>% ## df is your tibble given above
    group_by(Time) %>%
    ## compact the data apart from Time as dataframes per Time-group
    ## into column "nested_data"
    nest(nested_data = c(Site, Code, lon, lat)) %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(leaflet_map = list(
               base_map %>%
               addCircleMarkers(data = nested_data, ## the column of dataframes
                                label = ~as.character(Site),
                                radius = 5, 
                                color = ~statecol(Code),
                                stroke = FALSE,
                                fillOpacity = 5
                                )
           )
           ) %>%
           select(Time, leaflet_map)
```

The resulting tibble can be filtered and iterated (over column *leaflet_plot*) for automated map display.

```
## for single map at Time == -25
all_plots %>% 
    filter(Time == -25) %>%
    pull(leaflet_map) %>%
    print
```

Find solutions to display multiple maps in one go here: [Multiple leaflets in a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175040/multiple-leaflets-in-a-grid)

Comment: Thanks what I usually do is make all the plots into a GIF

Comment: maybe here's some helpful code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508486/create-a-gif-from-a-series-of-leaflet-maps-in-r , or - if no interactivity needed - ggmap might come in handy, esp. the convenient saving in var. file formats: https://cfss.uchicago.edu/notes/raster-maps-with-ggmap/